# Looping over rows in CUDA + Numba

Tags: python, cuda, numba

I'm doing a dynamic programming problem where each row is dependent on the previous row, i.e. the `i`th row is dependent on the `i-1`th row, beginning from row 1 (0-indexed).

I'm using `numba`'s `cuda.jit` to accelerate this. My approach is to have a 1D block of threads equal to the width (`w`) of my matrix (where the matrix is a greyscaled image, i.e. a 2D img of dimensions `h` x `w`). *Each thread is therefore responsible for a single column.*

How do I loop over each row correctly? In my code below, I make strides along the rows, since each thread handles a column.

```
@cuda.jit
def forward_energy(im, energy, m):
  row, col = cuda.grid(2)
  xstride, _ = cuda.gridsize(2)

  height, width = im.shape[0], im.shape[1]

  if row >= height or col >= width: return


  for i in range(row, im.shape[0], xstride):
      # example code below is dependent on the previous row of `im`
      energy[i, col] = min(im[i - 1, col], im[i - 1, col - 1])
      im[i, col] = # update current row
```

Is this right? As far as I'm aware, each thread executes asynchronously, so thread 1 (handling column 1) might be on row 5 and thread 2 (on column 2) might still be on row 3. **How do I ensure each row is completed before moving on**, if it is at all possible with cuda?

Comment: The only person who can say whether the code is right is you, by performing rigorous verification testing against know solutions. But I am highly skeptical that a computation which requires strict execution ordering for correctness will port directly to CUDA

Comment: Fair enough @talonmies. I read a paper on a similar problem that synchronized after each row. Could you point me in the right direction, in terms of how the implementation would look like if I were to synchronise after each row?

Comment: You can't do that sort of synchronization unless you vastly reduce the calculation to a single block. Numba doesn't support any of the more advanced arbitrary synchronization features in modern CUDA and hardware

Comment: The other option is to have your numba `@cuda.jit` function perform the computation for a single row, then call that function in a loop, for each row.  If you have a large enough number of columns, it may still be  sensible to use the GPU that way.

Comment: Thanks Robert. Yeah, that was the approach that I've gone with now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, this was my approach in the end:

1. I removed the strides from the code above.
2. Added a `for` loop that invoked a new kernel:

```
for row in range(1, image.shape[0]):
  forward_energy[(1,),(1, image.shape[1])](row, imd, ed, md)
  cuda.synchronize()
```

and updated the function arguments to take in the row:

```
def foward_energy(row, im, energy, m):
    # algo stuff
```

This [thread](https://github.com/TDAmeritrade/stumpy/issues/245) was a useful read on asynchronous kernel calls and how they behave.
I'm not entirely sure the `cuda.synchronize()` was necessary before the run of the next loop, but I'd rather err on the side of caution.

**Update (23/12/2020)**:

While the solution above worked fine, it was painfully slow. Thankfully Numba is about to release cooperative groups in `0.53` (according to their github milestone). If you're reading this after 0.53 has been released, then go straight to the code below; if not, you can use the latest numba with this [setup guide](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/developer/contributing.html#getting-set-up). That would give you access to numba's [cooperative groups](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cuda/cooperative_groups.html), `cuda.cg`, allowing you to perform a grid-wide sync.

The solution basically removes the need for multiple kernel launches. Earlier, the for-loop was hoisted out of the kernel, the code now has the for-loop in the kernel:

```
threads_per_block = 128
blocks_per_grid = math.ceil(image.shape[1] / threads_per_block)
```

Loop over the rows ***within*** the kernel:

```
@cuda.jit
def forward_energy(im, *args):
    col = cuda.grid(1)
    g = cuda.cg.this_grid()
    for row in range(1, im.shape[0]):
         # do stuff
         g.sync()
```

Invoking the kernel once:

```
forward_energy[blocks_per_grid, threads_per_block](im, *args)
```

That's it. Much faster than the previous way of managing sequential rows. What `g.sync()` does, as I understand it, is that every thread needs to invoke `g.sync()` before it can move onto the next loop. This has the effect of forcing every row to be executed in sequence. Good stuff.

Comment: You appear to be reducing your kernel launch to a single block.  Two comments: 1. That isn't a good way to get performance out of a GPU.  Depending on the size of your `image.shape[1]` you may get better results with a different distribution of blocks and threads  2. If you really are going to launch only 1 block, there is no need to hoist the for-loop out of the kernel.  As indicated to you previously in the comments, the 1 block approach means you could use a block-level synchronization, i.e. `cuda.syncthreads()`.

Comment: I didn't know about the `syncthreads`, thanks. Yeah the actual code won't be using a single block approach, I just used that in the answer for brevity. The actual approach would be to compute the block/thread sizes based on the image width, but still with the `for` loop on the rows

Comment: I'll try the method you suggested with having the for-loop inside the kernel function, and calling `syncthreads` and see how that fares. Thanks again!

Comment: If you do that, you will have to stay with the single block launch.

Comment: Yep, got it. Thanks

Comment: Please remember to come back and accept your answer so this question falls off the unanswered queue for the CUDA tag